# PHP echo total number of approved comment gives error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

In my current project I have a ternary foreach loop to display the top five posts.  That's working fine. Within the table I want to echo out the total number of approved comments.  When I try the code below I get the error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, user, password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
?>

<?php
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE id =' .$post['id']. ' AND status = "ON"';
    $stmt->execute();
    $commentCount = $stmt->fetch();
    echo $commentCount;
?>
```

I tried using array_shift but got another error message `Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in`

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE id =' .$post['id']. ' AND status = "ON"';
   $stmt->execute();
   $commentCount = $stmt->fetch();
   $result = array_shift($commentCount);
   echo $result;
?>
```

Since I'm new to PHP and PDO I'm struggling to understand where I am going wrong.  Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Try using `var_dump($commentCount);` to see what it contains.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You didn't show how connection is initialized and how your $stmt is prepared. When all is ok then you can update your SQL to add alias some thing like SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM comments...... then you can fetch data likr $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and then dump the result.

Comment: where is $sql is used ?

Comment: Here's the var dump with array_shift

` /app/public/dashboard.php:109: object(stdClass)[2]   public 'id' => int 26   public 'datetime' => string 'Jul 14th 2020 20:18 PM' (length=22)   public 'title' => string 'Testing with sessions enabled' (length=29)   public 'category' => string 'JQuery' (length=6)   public 'author' => string 'Steve Shead' (length=11)   public 'image' => string '' (length=0)   public 'post' => string 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...' (length=445) –`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Since you use PDO, you can use something like this :

```
<?php

$post['id'] = 1;
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE id = ? AND status = ?");
$stm->bindValue(1, $post['id']);
$stm->bindValue(2, 'ON');
$stm->execute();
$countResult = $stm->fetchColumn();
echo $countResult; // Count result here
```

Comment: Ah - I get the point of how the statement is being prepared - I added it to the post.  I'm trying to get the number of comments per post_id - did I do something wrong with the query?

Comment: @SteveShead I've added another solution to your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

$commentCount is an array. Try and You will find solution:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as countnum FROM comments WHERE id =' .$post['id']. ' AND status = "ON"';
 $stmt->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute();
   $commentCount = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($commentCount);
echo $commentCount['countnum'];
```

Comment: Thank you - this gives the output

`/app/public/dashboard.php:109:
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'id' => int 26
  public 'datetime' => string 'Jul 14th 2020 20:18 PM' (length=22)
  public 'title' => string 'Testing with sessions enabled' (length=29)
  public 'category' => string 'JQuery' (length=6)
  public 'author' => string 'Steve Shead' (length=11)
  public 'image' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'post' => string 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...' (length=445)`

Comment: take a look at my edit answer, added line $stmt->prepare($sql);

Comment: var_dump gives `app/public/dashboard.php:110:
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'countnum' => int 0` - but it's throwing an error on the echo statement

Comment: Steve, maybe try: echo $commentCount->countnum; - becouse You are using "PDO::FETCH_OBJ" attribute.

Comment: Another good one - thanks - I'm getting used to the differences with PDO and should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize - I figured it out.  The comments table has a column called post_id, which relates to the id column in the posts table.  I was using the wrong id - as well as not using the `AS myCount` statement. Here's what ended up working:

```
<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS myCount FROM comments WHERE post_id =' .$post['id']. ' AND status = "ON"';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $commentCount = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $commentCount['myCount'];
?>
```

I should have known to look more closely at the table I was referencing - but do appreciate those that tried to help.  By using your guidance as well as finding my error I was able to rectify it.  Thanks you!